Snowflake to Power Apps connection
Our organization has a Snowflake instance and we use SSO to log in to our accounts. We use Azure AD.
I am trying to connect PowerApps to Snowflake and as per the official Snowflake documentation (link below), I need to create/configure OAuth in Azure AD.
I don’t understand why this step is needed and do I change the existing Snowflake configuration in AAD or create a new application in AAD?
And while creating this OAuth configuration where would I mention specific details about the Power Platform?
Will appreciate any help.
https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/power_apps_snowflake/index.html?index=..%2F..index#2
Still gathering information of what is required.

Power Products are from Microsoft. Hence, you shall have to use the external Oauth.
Oauth Configuration with Powerapps
Once this is configured, You shall have to create a security integration on snowflake to read the token from the azure Oauth server.
External Oauth
As You also have the SSO security integration configured, you might get into errors while creating a new security integration hence you can modify the existing integration which you have.
Please refer to the following article whcih the steps which you shall have to follow:
Update the security integration
